# Welcome Listener Does Not Work(Java Discord JDA)

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm trying to make my bot welcome someone whenever someone joins but I can't seem to get it to work. For example(this will appear in an embed by the way):

```
@Jason joined. You must construct additional pylons.
```

Can someone help me edit my code so it works please?

Here's my Main code:

```
import Events.*;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("I imported key here");
        jda.setActivity(Activity.watching("baldness"));

        jda.addEventListeners(new Help());
        jda.addEventListeners(new PingPong());
        jda.addEventListeners(new Clear());
        jda.addEventListeners(new Welcome());

        jda.build();

    }
}
```

and Here's my Welcome code:

```
package Events;

import java.util.Random;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.member.GuildMemberJoinEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Welcome extends ListenerAdapter {

    public class GuildMemberJoin extends ListenerAdapter {

        String[] messages = {
                "[member] joined. You must construct additional pylons.",
                "Never gonna give [member] up. Never let [member] down!",
                "Hey! Listen! [member] has joined!",
                "Ha! [member] has joined! You activated my trap card!",
                "We've been expecting you, [member].",
                "It's dangerous to go alone, take [member]!",
                "Swoooosh. [member] just landed.",
                "Brace yourselves. [member] just joined the server.",
                "A wild [member] appeared."
        };

        public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int number = rand.nextInt(messages.length);

            EmbedBuilder join = new EmbedBuilder();
            join.setColor(0x66d8ff);
            join.setDescription(messages[number].replace("[member]", event.getMember().getAsMention()));

            event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel().sendMessage(join.build()).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation fo GuildMemberJoinEvent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/member/GuildMemberJoinEvent.html) clearly states:

> ### Requirements
>
> This event requires the GUILD_MEMBERS intent to be enabled.
> createDefault(String) and createLight(String) disable this by default!

So you must *enable the intent*. Read more in the wiki guide [Gateway Intents and Member Cache Policy](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy)

Additionally, you have a nested class for no reason which means you register the enclosing class as a listener but not the nested class that actually implements it.

Better:

```java
public class Welcome extends ListenerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
    ...
  }
}
```